# numpy array to the just number in the array

Tags: python, numpy

I got array list looks like

> [array(99.75142857), array(99.79928571), array(99.82238095),
>   array(99.83857143), array(99.85), array(99.85738095),
>   array(99.86285714), array(99.86767857)]

I'm not sure what is this array but I just want to ge a numbers 
[99.75142857,99.79928571....]

this array() means numpy array

Comment: This is a list of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

What you here have is a *list* of numpy arrays. Each array wraps a single element.

You can construct a list of elements, by first wrapping the list in an array:

```
import numpy as np

np.array(my_data)
```

this will produce an array with eight elements:

```
>>> np.array(my_data)
array([99.75142857, 99.79928571, 99.82238095, 99.83857143, 99.85      ,
       99.85738095, 99.86285714, 99.86767857])
```

Or if you want to convert this to a Python list:

```
>>> list(np.array(my_data))
[99.75142857, 99.79928571, 99.82238095, 99.83857143, 99.85, 99.85738095, 99.86285714, 99.86767857]
```

Answer (score 0):

A numpy array of rank 0 is a scalar (it's got shape `()`)  and will behave like a scalar everyone. You can treat it like that.

You're perhaps mixing it up with an array of rank 1, e.g., `np.array([99.79928571])`.

You can also wrap your list into `np.array` to get an array of `float64`. Perhaps that looks nicer to your eye.